# How to filter an attribute by all value of another XPATH

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I'm in an XSL page, i need to count all node where field Party is equal to a value.

Or to say differently ( I roughly rebuild the logic... you should have the point...)
I need all Teachers that got AT LEAST 5 students

- Teachers: `/School/Teachers/@Id`
- Students: `/School/Students/@TeachersId`

I can count, but I can't filter...
I got something like this

`count(/School/Students/@TeachersId = /School/Teachers/@Id)>5`

BUT this is counting the numbers of students to any teachers! I need only the teachers that got MORE than 5 students.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] showing an example input, your current XSLT and the expected output. Also clarify which version of XSLT your processor supports.

Comment: P.S. If a student is related to a teacher by the teacher's id, you should define a **key** that matches a student by `@TeachersId`. Then you can select the teachers that have more than 5 students by using the predicate `[count(key('student', @Id)) > 5]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an [`xsl:key`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2021/REC-xslt20-20210330/#xsl-key) on the `Students` using their `@TeachersId` as the lookup key:

```
<xsl:key
    name="students-by-teacher-id"
    match="Students"
    use="@TeachersId"/>
```

and then for each `Teachers`, you can use the key to select all of the `Students` that have that `Teachers/@Id` value for their `@TeachersId` and `count()` them to test whether there are more than 5 inside of a predicate.

```
 /School/Teachers/@Id[count(key('students-by-teacher-id', .)) > 5]
```